# What is the difference between L2_NORM and NORM_MINMAX implementation in cv::Normalise()?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to replicate the Dense optical flow as discussed here : https://nanonets.com/blog/optical-flow/ 
.This is the snippet , I have used to process each frame for optical flow.
The intution is that H->Angle of gradient,S->255,V->Norm value of Magnitude of gradient.The gradient is from output of calcOpticalFlowFarenback.

```
       cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray,gray,flow,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0);
       cv::split(flow,channels);
       cv::cartToPolar(channels[0],channels[1],mag,angle);




       std::vector<cv::Mat> channels_m;
       cv::Mat c1 (Mask.size(),CV_8UC1);
       cv::Mat c0 (Mask.size(),CV_8UC1);
       cv::Mat c2 (Mask.size(),CV_8UC1);
       c1 = cv::Scalar::all(255);
       c0= angle*((180/3.14)/2);
       c0.convertTo(c0, CV_8U);
       cv::normalize(mag,c2,0,255,cv::NORM_MINMAX); <----- Line of interest
       c2.convertTo(c2, CV_8U);
       channels_m.push_back(c0);
       channels_m.push_back(c1);
       channels_m.push_back(c2);

       cv::merge(channels_m,Mask);
       cv::cvtColor(Mask,cflow,cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL);
```

when norm type cv::NORM_L2 is used , my entire V array of HSV is returning nothing but zero . However when changed to cv::NORM_MINMAX, It returns non zero values .I thought the actual function of cv::normalise is to normalise an array within the range alpha and beta . The Norm is just type of normalisation formula used to achieve the ranging objective. So why do we see a difference in output ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cv::NORM_L2` normalises your data such that if you took the entire image and converted it into one long vector, the **magnitude** of this vector is such that it becomes `alpha`.  `beta` is ignored in the normalisation. 
 Therefore, once you normalise by `cv::NORM_L2`, after you normalise if you were to consider this normalised input as one long vector, the L<sub>2</sub> norm of this vector thus becomes `alpha`.  Because you specified `alpha = 0`, it's not surprising that the output image is entirely 0 because you are specifying that the norm needs to be 0 after normalisation.

`cv::NORM_MINMAX` uses both `alpha` and `beta` such that the smallest value in the input array gets mapped to `alpha` and the largest value gets mapped to `beta` with all values in between scaled proportionally.

If you're wondering how I know this, the documentation for the function makes this very clear: https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd